# Prove that the norm of a linear transformation satisfies the inequality $\|Tx\| \leq M\|x\|$ for all $x$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Proof.

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator.

Then $$\|T\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$$

So $\|T\| \geq \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$, that is, $\|T\|\cdot\|x\|\geq \|Tx\|$.

I'm not understand if I let $M=\|T\|$. Is this proof correct?

Comment: That's right, that's all you need to do.

Comment: I suggest that you write the answer by yourself.

Comment: See also: [Proof that $||fx|| \leq ||f||\cdot||x||$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1944895).

Answer (score 1):

A linear transformation is a continous function and if we keep account by linearity is suficiently to prove  the afirmation for x with ||x||=1and that domain is compact so there exist M=sup||T(x)|| when ||x||=1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $M=\|T\|$ the inequality is true by definition of operator norm (with the remark that it obviously holds also for $x=0$).

On the other hand, if the inequality is satisfied for some $M$, then the set $\{\|T(x)\|/\|x\|: x\ne0\}$ is bounded from above and so it has a supremum.

The problem might be that you start with a bounded operator (so it sends the unit sphere around $0$ into a bounded sphere around $0$) and want to establish the existence of $M$, which then will allow to define the operator norm. By assumption you know that, if $\|x\|<1$, then $\|Tx\|<k$ for some $k$; but then
$$
\left\|\frac{1}{2\|x\|}x\right\|<1
\qquad\text{implies}\qquad
\left\|\frac{1}{2\|x\|}Tx\right\|<k
$$
for all $x\ne0$ and we are able to find an $M$ to start with.