# Proof that $\|fx\| \leq \|f\|\cdot\|x\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

From the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Topology) on the dual of a norm:

$X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces, and we associate with each $f\in L(X,Y)$ (the space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$) the number
$$\|f\| = \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X, \|x\| \leq 1\}.$$

At some point in the proof that $L(X,Y)$ is bounded, it seems like they use the inequality
$$\|fx\| \leq \|f\|\cdot\|x\|,$$
where $\|x\|\leq 1$.

I can't see why this should holds.

$\|f|\|$ is the supremum of what $|f(x)|$ can be, given that $\|x\|\leq 1$. So, given that $\|x\| \leq 1$, $|fx|$ should be bounded by $\|f\|$. But why should it be bounded by $\|f\|\cdot\|x\|$?

Comment: If $y$ is the normalised version of $x$, then apply the bound $|fy|\leq || f ||$, and you will get the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality is clearly true if $x=0$. If $x\not=0$ write
$$x=||x||\dfrac{x}{||x||}=||x||\cdot y$$
where $y=x/||x||$ has norm 1. The definition of the operator norm gives that
$$||fy||\leq ||f||$$
hence
$$\left|\left|f\left(\dfrac{x}{||x||}\right)\right|\right|\leq ||f|| \Rightarrow ||fx||\leq ||f||\cdot||x||$$
by linearity.

Comment: In the rightmost hand side of the first line of equalities, I'll take it as it should be $||x||\cdot y$?